# Including JS files in template.php to control weight/order/group

Tags: 7, javascript

I'm looking to include a few JS files (some libraries, others are custom modules with dependencies on libraries). Originally I had all JS files added through our .info file, and while I could control the order of the files manually my moving them up and down, that would result in all the JS files loading on every page.

Is it a better idea to add JS files through template.php in the template_preprocess_html function? For each JS file I can attach a group property (one of the constants of JS_Library, JS_DEFAULT, or JS_THEME) to control the ordering, and also control which pages need to load which files.

Thoughts?

Comment: Assuming your question as How to include js page specifically. Answer can be drupal_add_js() is what you are looking for. [for example](https://drupal.org/sandbox/Gajendrasharma/2055613)

Comment: @arpitr The question is really what is the best place to add .js files that should be included on every page, but should be included in the JS_LIBRARY or JS_THEME group. It seems the 2 options are to add them to the .info file and then change their group in `hook_js_alter()` or to add all of them in `template_preprocess_html()`, which would certainly work but I'm not sure if it has drawbacks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [JS injector module](https://drupal.org/project/js_injector) which provides an UI for that